# How to get a csv output of hive table without table name as part of column

Tags: csv, hive

By using this command :

```
hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;
SELECT * FROM hive_to_csv ;" | sed 's/[\t]/~/g' > hive_to_csv".CSV
```

But getting the table name also as part of the CSV column headers... I only need the column name sans the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below property before your `select` statement!

**`set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false`**

Then hive doesn't printout the tablename as part of column names.